# Solve the Diophantine equation $y^3=4x^2+4x+5$ in $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have to solve the Diophantine equation $y^3=4x^2+4x+5$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and I have been thinking now for a long time and I have really no clue how to do this. The only hint given in the exercise was that I have to factorise it in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I really need more hints if I want to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: **Hint:** $4x^2+4x+5=(2x)^2+2\cdot2x+1+4=(2x+1)^2+2^2=(2x+1-2i)(2x+1+2i)$.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks! Now I can continue :)